# Enable constructor iff two member functions are present in the passed template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

With this code:

```
struct MyStructure {
  MyStructure(char* d, int size) {}

  template <typename T>
  MyStructure(T&& rhs) : MyStructure(rhs.data(), rhs.size()) {}
};
```

How can I only enable the second constructor to be present if the `data` and `size` functions are present in whatever object is passed in?

Comment: This is textbook SFINAE, `decltype(static_cast<char *>(std::declval<T &&>().data()))`, and another, equivalent one, specified as optional template parameters for the constructor. Maybe, to make it a bit cleaner, toss them into a `std::void_t`. I'm just too lazy to write out this entire novel, someone else who wants karma can do that.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you targeting? In C++20, this can be done with `requires` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what Sam Varshavchik meant, which should work with C++11:

```
struct MyStructure {
  MyStructure(char* d, int size) {}

  template <typename T, 
     decltype(static_cast<char*>(std::declval<T &&>().data())) = nullptr,
     decltype(static_cast<int>(std::declval<T &&>().size())) = 0
     >
  MyStructure(T&& rhs) : MyStructure(rhs.data(), rhs.size()) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please explain how that works, or point me to a link so I can read about it myself?

Comment: Read about SFINAE.